# Jquery анимация двух элементов одновременно

Tags: javascript, jquery

Сейчас пытаюсь анимировать элементы с помощью jQuery, при анимировании одного элемента всё нормально работает, но если я пытаюсь анимировать сразу два элемента одновременно (в одной функции) один из них сначала куда-то уплывает, потом откуда-то с непонятного места выплывает. Результат-то вроде правильный, но вопрос в том, что он куда-то убегает при вызове функции. Как это убрать?

Вот верстка и JS:

```js
function mobileFind() {
  if ($('.mobile_find_form').css('display') == 'none') {
    $('.mobile_find_form').animate({
      height: 'show'
    }, 300);
    var newHeight = $('.container-fluid').height() - 80;
    $('.container-fluid').animate({
      minHeight: newHeight
    }, 300);
  } else {
    $('.mobile_find_form').animate({
      height: 'hide'
    }, 300);
    var notNewHeight = $('.container-fluid').height() + 80;
    $('.container-fluid').animate({
      minHeight: notNewHeight
    }, 300);
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="logo_header text-center">
  <a href="/" class="header_img"><img src="../img/logo.png" alt="Logotype"></a>
  <div style="display: inline-block; height: 100%" class="site_desc">
    <a href="/">Title of site</a>
    <h2>Description of site</h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="menu">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="/" class="main">Main</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC6PGsdUw2eeVbUWpTevGUEQ" class="yt">YouTube channel</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="about" class="about">
      About us
     </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="support" class="support">
      Support
     </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="find">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="mobile_find">
          <img src="../img/search.svg" alt="Поиск" onclick="mobileFind()">
          <!-- Это иконка лупы -->
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<!-- div ниже изначально имеет display: none -->

<div class="mobile_find_form">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <form class="find_form text-center" method="GET" action="search">
          <input name="s" placeholder="Искать здесь..." type="search" minlength="3" maxlength="30" autocomplete="off" required="">
          <button type="submit">Найти</button>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

вот видео, как оно получается: (при первом клике на иконку все плохо, потом - нормально): https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Fs7_FUmprEZbc_sxKCHPahfWeuwolXCJ

Comment: нужно где-то поменять код

Comment: ну, я не знаю, честно говоря, что тут менять надо.. Вот функция: ```if ( $('.mobile_find_form').css('display') == 'none' ) {
 $('.mobile_find_form').animate({height: 'show'}, 300);
 var newHeight = $('.container-fluid').height() - 80;
 $('.container-fluid').animate({minHeight: newHeight}, 300);
 } else {
 $('.mobile_find_form').animate({height: 'hide'}, 300);
 var notNewHeight = $('.container-fluid').height() + 80;
 $('.container-fluid').animate({minHeight: notNewHeight}, 300);
 }```

Comment: Добавь весь код вместе с версткой в вопрос

Comment: добавил верстку и js

Comment: И что не работает? Нажимаешь на иконку - поиск появляется, нажимаешь ещё раз - поиск прячется. Элемента с классом `container-fluid` я в вёрстке не нашел, если с ним проблемы

Comment: добавил видео, посмотри. при первом заходе на страницу футер дёргается, последующие разы - норм

Comment: Какой футер? Ты ведь понимаешь, что по видео ничего нельзя понять, тем более по тому, что ты скинул?https://jsfiddle.net/xg5jmu6h/